# Why the user name or password for twitter is shown incorrect iOS 6 device settings twitter login?

Tags: ios, ipad, twitter, ios6.1

Team,

Today when I tried to login to twitter in my iPad's settings app. It is throwing username and password is incorrect, even I have given correct credentials.

My iPad has iOS 6.1 OS.

Why its hapenning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just thought of sharing this in this forum.

After struggling for a long time, found that my iPad system time was set to the past date. This was the reason for the login error.

But I am disappointed that, its throwing wrong error.